# spring cloud gateway predicates test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, predicate, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented the predicate factory(spring cloud gateway) to validate the headers and I want to add the test cases for that

```
public Predicate<ServerWebExchange> apply(Config config ) {
    return (ServerWebExchange t) -> {
        
        List<String> Header = t.getRequest().getHeaders().get("abcd");
        #business logic
        return true;
    };

}
```

I want to include the test cases for the predicate factory above.

I tried the test case as below

```
@Before
public void prepareStubs() {
    
    stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/abcd")).willReturn(aResponse().withBody("ABCD")));
    
}

@Test
public void testGatewayRouting() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer eyJraWQiOiIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9");
            
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    
    
    UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(createURLWithPort("/abcd"));
    
    

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity,
            String.class);

    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCodeValue());

    assertEquals("ABCD", response.getBody());
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with what have you tried so far and what issue you faced with it

Comment: updated what i have tried in the question

Comment: And what error/issue are you facing with your test case?

Comment: No error and it's not covering the predicate factory

Comment: Which runner are you using to run test case? Are you creating the spring context and necessary config in the test case for predicate factory to execute?